# Calling function of a struct imported via plugin

Tags: go

I've a following plugin:

```
package main

type Test struct {
    Id string
}

func (test *Test) GetId() string {
    return test.Id
}

var V Test
```

I'm importing it within my app:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "plugin"
)

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("test.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    v, err := p.Lookup("V")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to call `v.getId()` on it - is there a way to expose all functions that are set on the given struct?

Comment: Normally you know what you want to call, so you don't need to "expose all functions that are set on the given struct". You're not calling any methods in your example, but the `plugin` docs show how to assert various types in the examples there.

Comment: @JimB - I don't understand what do you mean. How can I call the `GetId` function that is created within this plugin? I don't see that within the `plugin` docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Lookup`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Plugin.Lookup) returns a [`Symbol`](https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/#Symbol), which is just an empty interface. In order to use this you need to assert the type you want. The documentation for `Symbol` example shows both symbols asserted to the expected types:

```
v, err := p.Lookup("V")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
f, err := p.Lookup("F")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
*v.(*int) = 7
f.(func())() // prints "Hello, number 7"
```

To do that in your program, create the type you want, which in this case is an interface because you're looking for a particular method set (see the ["Tour of Go" section on interfaces](https://tour.golang.org/methods/9), esp implicit implementation and type assertion)

Here we create the `V` interface in the main program to define the method we want, than use a type assertion on the symbol returned from `Lookup`:

```
type V interface {
    GetId() string
}

func main() {
    p, err := plugin.Open("plugin.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    s, err := p.Lookup("V")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    v := s.(V)

    fmt.Println(v.GetId())
}
```

Comment: So, in my main program I'll still have to create an interface that is a reflection of the struct defined within the plugin (or at least the part that I'll be using) and then cast given looked-up variable to a type defined within my main program. I've read `export` in the docs to mean that I'll have access to all methods defined for given struct, which is sadly not the case. Thank you very much - your example did help

Comment: @eithed, you do have access to the methods, otherwise this type assertion wouldn't work at all. `Lookup` however has no way of knowing what you expect it to return, so you need to put the type assertion in there in order to use the value.

Comment: I think of it the other way round - I don't have access to the methods until I cast given object to a type defined within my main app that exposes them; still there's a knowledge about what the given type given thing is, as when I do `reflect.TypeOf(s)` I do indeed get correct type (`*main.Test`); I simply would like to have access to that type, rather than doing a cast